# Problema na verificação do tipo de variáveis INT

Tags: php

Estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo entender, estou passando duas `variáveis`para a página `produtos`, os valores são `int`, nessa página estou recebendo as variáveis e testando se as mesmas são realmente `int` e `sanitizando` as mesmas, mas o teste sempre cai na exceção "Valor Incorreto".

O que tenho é isso:

```
if (is_numeric($_GET['dep'])) {  
$dep = Sanitize::filter($_GET['dep']); 
} else {  
    die ("Valor Incorreto") ;  
}

if (is_numeric($_GET['sub'])) {  
$sub  = Sanitize::filter($_GET['sub']); 
} else {  
    die ("Valor Incorreto") ;  
}
```

Posso estar passando por alto algo muito simples, mas sinceramente não consegui vê-lo.

Comment: produtos é quantidade ou valor monetário?

Comment: Olá @rray, são valores de departamentos e subdepartamentos, não sei se responde a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sanitização normalmente vem antes da validação. O que montou faz o contrário. Tenta validar para depois sanitizar mas como não deve estar recebendo o tipo apropriado, cai sempre na mensagem de erro.

Uma maneira de sanitizar é fazendo um cast do tipo usando `intval()` ou precedendo `(int)`.

```
$var = (int)$var;
```

ou

```
$var = intval($var);
```

No entanto, cuidado com o uso do type casting para o que está fazendo pois nas versões recentes do PHP pode não funcionar como esperado. É mais seguro fazer uma substituição de caracteres usando funções de manipulação de strings para performar uma sanitização consistente. E lembrando que o cast em si já é uma sanitização para o caso em questão.

Exemplo (PHP5.6.19):

```
// http://localhost/tmp.php?n=a
echo (int)$_GET['n'];
```

Esse teste acima retorna inteiro ZERO. É um resultado inesperado pois o valor recebido não contém nenhum número.

**Uma forma mais consistente** é por substituição de caracteres não numéricos:

```
function numbers_only($str, $exception = '')
{
    return preg_replace('#[^0-9'.$exception.']#', '', mb_convert_kana($str, 'n'));
}

// http://localhost/tmp.php?n=a
echo '<br>numbers_only(): '.numbers_only($_GET['n']);
```

Nesse exemplo, como não há números, retorna vazio pois a sanitização removeu tudo que não foi reconhecido como caracter numérico.

Repare que também auto converte caracteres zenkaku, permitindo que números zenkaku sejam sanitizados para o padrão ASCII com a função [mb_convert_kana()](http://php.net/mb_convert_kana).

Adaptando para o seu caso, ficaria algo assim

```
// Checking if parameter exists
$n = isset($_GET['dep'])? $_GET['dep']: null;

// Checking if the parameter is not empty or equals to ZERO
if (!empty($n) || $n == '0') {
    // Sanitization
    $n = numbers_only($n);

    // Check again if not empty and different of ZERO
    if (empty($n) && $n != '0') {
        $err = 'parameter do not contains numbers';
    }
} else {
    $err = 'parameter cannot be empty';
}

if (empty($err)) {
    echo 'number: '.$n;
} else {
    echo 'error: '.$err;
}
```

No exemplo acima é aceito o valor 0 (ZERO). Caso queira remover o zero, remova-o das condicionais `|| $n == '0')` e `&& $n != '0'`.